# Yii popup confirmation

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying my best to alter the below code so that it produces a popup box with a warning and asking for confirmation.

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton(Yii::t('mc', 'Wipe Server'), '', array(
        'type'=>'POST', 'data'=>array('ajax'=>'wipe', Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName=>Yii::app()->request->csrfToken,),
        'success'=>'function(e) {if (e) alert(e);}'
    ),
```

I expect adding `'confirm' => 'Wipe your server?'` to add a dialog box but I'm not having much success.

I have this in ServerController:

```
        case 'wipe':
            if (Yii::app()->user->can($id, 'wipe'))
            {
                if (!McBridge::get()->serverCmd($id, 'run:builtin:script wipe'))
                    echo McBridge::get()->lastError();
            }
            break;
```

I would be grateful if anyone can point out where I am going wrong or generally point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one
In Yii ajax button, beforesend function is there. Use that.

**Example**

```
 <?php
        echo CHtml::ajaxButton(
                'Submit',
                array('controlleraction'),
                array(
                    'success' => 'js:
                                function (data){

                                }
                            ',
                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'beforeSend' => 'js:
                                function(){
                                   var r = confirm("Are you sure?");
                           if(!r){return false;} 
                                }
                               ',
        ));
    ?>
```